# App simulates perfectly in SDK 2.2.1 but collapses when i run it in Simulator 3.0

Tags: iphone

I started building an app in SDK 2.2.1 and i have now completed it . Now when i try to run it in simulator 3.0 it collapses at runtime and i get the following message in gdb

"Loading program into debugger…
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-965) (Mon Feb 16 20:24:53 UTC 2009)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i386-apple-darwin".warning: Unable to read symbols for "/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "UIKit" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "CoreGraphics" (not yet mapped into memory).
Program loaded.
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all "

Could some one please tell me how to get over this problem as i took lot of pains to complete and app and make it work :( and now it doesnt work with version 3.0 .

Comment: Have you recompiled your program from **scratch** since upgrading the dev kit to 3.0? It seems like the code was linked to libraries that have moved or no longer exist.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a "clean all targets" and see if that gets you anywhere. The good news here is that this does not look like a problem with your code. This is a linking issue.